# get number of hours of specific timeperiod in another timeperiod

Tags: javascript, algorithm, typescript

Struggling with that very much so let me pain You a scenario:

waiter at restaurant earns 15$/hour but between 21.00 and 02.30 he gets paid additionaly 3$/hour. now what I have is 'start' and the 'end' of the shift as Date -object and I want to calculate how many hours of that extra paid-period is in the shift if there is any.(keep in mind start and end time of shift can be anything-and bc of that it gets difficult)

I made it work by using alot of if-statements but that definitly can not be the right way of doing it. I'm adding my code here [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20class%20Shared%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20calculateShiftSalary(shift%3A%20Shift%2C%20employee%3A%20Employee)%3A%20Shift%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2FTODO%20check%20how%20it%20works%20when%20shift%20is%20between%2003%2F31%20and%2004%2F01%20add%20helgdagar%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20dateStart%20%3D%20new%20Date(shift.timeStempIn)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20dateEnd%20%3D%20new%20Date(shift.timeStempOut)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20endAtMidnight%20%3D%20false%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(dateEnd.getHours()%20%3D%3D%200%20%26%26%20dateEnd.getMinutes()%20%3D%3D%200)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20endAtMidnight%20%3D%20true%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20OBtime%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20OBnightTime%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(dateStart.getDay()%20%3D%3D%20dateEnd.getDay())%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20OBtime%20%3D%20Shared.getOBforSameDay(dateStart%2C%20dateEnd%2C%20endAtMidnight)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20OBnightTime%20%3D%20Shared.getNightOBforSameDay(dateStart%2C%20dateEnd%2C%20endAtMidnight)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('dif')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20OBtime%20%3D%20Shared.getOBforDifferentDays(dateStart%2C%20dateEnd%2C%20endAtMidnight)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20OBnightTime%20%3D%20Shared.getNightOBforDifferrentDays(dateStart%2C%20dateEnd%2C%20endAtMidnight)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20shift.OBnattHours%20%3D%20OBnightTime%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20shift.OBhours%20%3D%20OBtime%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20shift.OBmoney%20%3D%20OBtime%20*%20Shared.ob2018%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20shift.OBnattMoney%20%3D%20OBnightTime%20*%20Shared.obNatt2018%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20shift.employeeSalary%20%3D%20Sorter.sortSalaryRises(employee.salaries)%5B0%5D.salary%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20shift.employmentType%20%3D%20Sorter.sortSalaryRises(employee.salaries)%5B0%5D.employmentType%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20shift%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20static%20getOBforDifferentDays(dateStart%3A%20Date%2C%20dateEnd%3A%20Date%2C%20endAtMidnight%3A%20boolean)%3A%20number%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20part1start%20%3D%20dateStart%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20part1end%20%3D%20new%20Date(dateStart.getFullYear()%2C%20dateStart.getMonth()%2C%20dateStart.getDay()%2C%200%2C%200)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20part2start%20%3D%20new%20Date(dateEnd.getFullYear()%2C%20dateEnd.getMonth()%2C%20dateEnd.getDay()%2C%200%2C%200)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20part2end%20%3D%20dateEnd%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20part1%20%3D%20Shared.getOBforSameDay(part1start%2C%20part1end%2C%20true)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20part2%20%3D%20Shared.getOBforSameDay(part2start%2C%20part2end%2C%20false)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20part1%20%2B%20part2%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20static%20getOBforSameDay(dateStart%3A%20Date%2C%20dateEnd%3A%20Date%2C%20endShiftAtMidnight%3A%20boolean)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20OBindex1%20%3D%206%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20OBindex2%20%3D%2020%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20obHoursForFirstPeriod%20%3D%200%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20obHoursForSEcondPeriod%20%3D%200%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(dateStart.getDay()%20%3D%3D%200)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20OBindex2%20%3D%206%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(dateStart.getDay()%20%3D%3D%206)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20OBindex2%20%3D%2016%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20startTimeDecimal%20%3D%20dateStart.getHours()%20%2B%20(Math.round((dateStart.getMinutes()%20%2F%2060)%20*%20100)%20%2F%20100)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20endTimeDecimal%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(endShiftAtMidnight)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20endTimeDecimal%20%3D%2024%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20endTimeDecimal%20%3D%20dateEnd.getHours()%20%2B%20(Math.round((dateEnd.getMinutes()%20%2F%2060)%20*%20100)%20%2F%20100)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(dateStart.getHours()%20%3C%20OBindex1)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(dateEnd.getHours()%20%3C%20OBindex1)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20obHoursForFirstPeriod%20%3D%20endTimeDecimal%20-%20startTimeDecimal%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20obHoursForFirstPeriod%20%3D%20OBindex1%20-%20startTimeDecimal%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(endTimeDecimal%20%3E%20OBindex2)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(startTimeDecimal%20%3E%20OBindex2)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20obHoursForSEcondPeriod%20%3D%20(24%20-%20OBindex2)%20-%20((24%20-%20endTimeDecimal)%20%2B%20(startTimeDecimal%20-%20OBindex2))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20obHoursForSEcondPeriod%20%3D%20endTimeDecimal%20-%2020%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20obHoursForFirstPeriod%20%2B%20obHoursForSEcondPeriod%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20static%20getNightOBforSameDay(dateStart%3A%20Date%2C%20dateEnd%3A%20Date%2C%20endShiftAtMidnight%3A%20boolean)%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20nightOBindex1%20%3D%201%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20nightOBindex2%20%3D%206%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20lengthOfNightOB%20%3D%20nightOBindex2%20-%20nightOBindex1%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20nightOBhours%20%3D%200%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20startTimeDecimal%20%3D%20dateStart.getHours()%20%2B%20(Math.round((dateStart.getMinutes()%20%2F%2060)%20*%20100)%20%2F%20100)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20endTimeDecimal%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(endShiftAtMidnight)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20endTimeDecimal%20%3D%2024%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20endTimeDecimal%20%3D%20dateEnd.getHours()%20%2B%20(Math.round((dateEnd.getMinutes()%20%2F%2060)%20*%20100)%20%2F%20100)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(startTimeDecimal%20%3C%3D%20nightOBindex1)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(endTimeDecimal%20%3C%3D%20nightOBindex2)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20nightOBhours%20%3D%20endTimeDecimal%20-%20nightOBindex1%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20nightOBhours%20%3D%20lengthOfNightOB%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(nightOBindex2%20-%20startTimeDecimal%20%3E%200)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(endTimeDecimal%20%3C%3D%20nightOBindex2)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20nightOBhours%20%3D%20lengthOfNightOB%20-%20((startTimeDecimal%20-%20nightOBindex1)%20%2B%20(nightOBindex2%20-%20endTimeDecimal))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(nightOBhours%20%3C%200)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20nightOBhours%20%3D%200%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20nightOBhours%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20static%20getNightOBforDifferrentDays(dateStart%3A%20Date%2C%20dateEnd%3A%20Date%2C%20endShiftAtMidnight%3A%20boolean)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20part1start%20%3D%20dateStart%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20part1end%20%3D%20new%20Date(dateStart.getFullYear()%2C%20dateStart.getMonth()%2C%20dateStart.getDay()%2C%200%2C%200)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20part2start%20%3D%20new%20Date(dateEnd.getFullYear()%2C%20dateEnd.getMonth()%2C%20dateEnd.getDay()%2C%200%2C%200)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20part2end%20%3D%20dateEnd%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20part1%20%3D%20Shared.getNightOBforSameDay(part1start%2C%20part1end%2C%20true)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20part2%20%3D%20Shared.getNightOBforSameDay(part2start%2C%20part2end%2C%20false)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20part1%20%2B%20part2%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D) but It's a mess just so U know(have two different timeperiod with extra pay in that code fui). Any one have an idea of better way of calculate that?(any classes that can be of any help here?)

```
static calculateShiftSalary(shift: Shift, employee: Employee): Shift {
    const extraPaidStart = 22
    const extraPaidEnd= 2.5 // meaning 02.30 o'clock -of the next day here

    let start:Date = shift.startDate
    let end:Date = shift.endDate

    let extraHours:number = 
          getNumberOfExtraPaidHours(start,end,extraPaidStart,extraPaidEnd)
}
```

so if U'd would have a shift between 20.00 and 23.30 ->'extraHours'=1,5 and if shift would be between 23.00 and 02.00 ->extraHours=3h

extraPaidStart and extraPaidEnd can be change to a Date ofc if that would be to any help (y)

Comment: Please include the relevant code parts into your question, have a look at [mcve]

Comment: very sorry for that- but the way I calculated it is so bad that code snippet form it would not give any clearification to the question at all  - but I can delete the question in an hour if I will not get any answer (meaning that question was unclear) if You wish so...

Comment: No, i want to help you but that is not possible as the typescript page is not really responsive, so i cant access it on my phone. I just need some sample inputs and outputs to know what you want to get.

Comment: aha, ok:) - give me couple of minutes (y)

Comment: @JonasW. there You go (y) -added to question

Answer (score 1):

Lets take the easiest case first: Our worker just works one day. A timetable were the extra time goes over night would look like this:

```
extra paid ---|-- regular paying ---------|---- extra paid ---
      |--------- working time -----------------------------|
      |--- 1 -------|--------------- 2 ----------------|---- 3 ---|
```

And were the extra time just spans one day is actually more simple:

```
|----------- regular paying -------|------ extra paid ----|----|
    |------ working time -----------------|
    |-----  1 -----------------------------|- 2 -|
```

So we just have to calculate three different ranges that the worker worked in, all units are in minutes:

```
 function paymentRange(payment: number, start: number, end: number) {
    return function calculatePayment(startWorking: number, endWorking: number) {
      if(start < end) { 
        const rangeStart = Math.max(start, startWorking);
        const rangeEnd = Math.min(end, endWorking);
        return Math.max(rangeEnd - rangeStart, 0) / 60 * payment;
    } else {
       const morning =  Math.max(end - startWorking, 0);
       const evening = Math.max(endWorking - start, 0)
       return (morning + evening) / 60 * payment;
  }
 }
}
```

Now we just need a way to combine multiple payments:

```
 function combinedPayment(...payments) {
   return (start, end) => payments.reduce((sum, payment) => sum + payment(start, end), 0);
 }
```

So to get a payment for one day, we can just do:

```
 const calculatePayment = combinedPayment(
   paymentRange(3/*$*/, 22/*h*/ * 60, 2/*h*/ * 60 + 30/*min*/),
   paymentRange(15/*$*/, 0/*min*/, 24/*h*/ * 60)
);

 // If he worked from 1h to 22h:
calculatePayment(1/*h*/ * 60, 22/*h*/ * 60)
```

Now we only have to divide our date range into days, and calculate the payment for the days:

```
 const dateToMins = date => date.getHours() * 60 + date.getMinutes();

const toWholeDay = date => new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), 0, 0, 0);
const min = (a, b) => new Date(Math.min(+a, +b));
const max = (a, b) => new Date(Math.max(+a, +b));

 function paymentForDateRange(payment, start: Date, end: Date) {
  let pay = 0;
  let today = toWholeDay(start);
  while(+today < +end) {
    const nextDay = new Date(today + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
    const startWorking = max(start, today);
    const endWorking = min(end, nextDay);
    pay += payment(dateToMins(startWorking), dateToMins(endWorking));
   today = nextDay;
  }
  return pay;
}
```

So we can finally do:

```
paymentForDateRange(calculatePayment, new Date(), new Date())
```

*PS: I could not test every single part of this, it might not fully work*

Comment: Dear god sir, U did that fom your phone O.O -amazing - I'm trying to grasp evryting. U have:  if(endWorking >= start || startWorking >= end) return 0;  which means that in case of shift going from 15.00 to 23.30 it will return "0" when it should be 1,5 - or am I missing here something ? ( programming only in typescript  so it might be me being a bit of)

Comment: @pb4now yeah, that was a mistake :)

Comment: oo U fixed that already:) ty alot for your help sir. great help, thought that there maybe is already a class that takes two timespans and calculate shared timespen of thoese  but it seams that there is not always an easy way out:) ty again (y)

Comment: @pb4now glad to help :)

Comment: sadly have to inform that we still missing something in you code(or I just don't understand it:)) - tested  shift between 19.00-23.30 -that returned 0.5h when it should be 1.5 and and shift 19.00-03.00  returns 0; :S - what I think might be wrong is that in: '  if(start < end) { ' where  start=22 and end =2.5   it is not taken to cosideration that end happens on the next day , shouldn't we use timeStemp for 'start' and 'end' instead?    then when compering start<end  it will return true - but that would make it always return true :S

Comment: well,...if You put start=22, end =2.5 , statWorking=19, endWorking=23.5 it will go into 'else' statemant and  return (0.5 * payment ) when it should be (1.5*payment)

Comment: now if U put startWorking=19 , endWorking=3 -it will return 0 *payment (it should be 4,5*payment) - hehe - no winning here:)